# Why was Selina Kyle's character included in the Dark knight Rises?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

From [Wikia](http://dcmovies.wikia.com/wiki/Selina_Kyle_%28Nolanverse%29), we can see the importance of Selina Kyle's role in the [Dark Knight Rises](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836/). So what are the important tasks she achieved (with respect to *the movie only*)?

The only two things I can see (except the *cold kissing* :P):

1. By letting Bane catch Batman.
2. By killing Bane from behind (*what a shame*)!

All the other things that she did (like attacking Dagget etc) seemed to me a forceful addition to the script adding nothing constructive to the plot, except elongating the movie. The aforementioned tasks could be made done by another character easily, I believe. Like Batman could kill the Bane himself (which he almost did) and the traitor could be anybody else.

So my question is why the director chose to include the Catwoman character?

Comment: She was just another character that gave more depth to the story and allowed Nolan to showcase his flair. Thats it! Don't read too much into it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

She stole Bruce Wayne's finger-prints, allowing Bane to manipulate the shares of Wayne Enterprises on the stock market to set up Dagget to take over Wayne Enterprises.

This sub-plot (which also involved Miranda) would require a master thief, hence, Catwoman.

Comment: Ah! Thanks to remind. This theory seems to be related to the plot. Also +1 from me!

Answer (score 14):

Selina Kyle's importance I believe that Nolan went with adding Catwoman/Selina Kyle to the movie as a way to help Bruce out of the darkness he has put himself into. After becoming injured while trying to save Gordon's son from Harvey Dent, Bruce lives away from society. This is because he cannot see a life outside of being Batman, which he has since given up; his only motivation to put away his Batman persona was to be with Rachel, and since her death, he lacks the drive to move forward. This becomes aparent in the conversation Bruce has with Alfred after Bruce investigates Selina Kyle in the Batcave.

In interviews I recall from the Blu Ray in the "A Girl's Gotta Eat" segment, Bale and Nolan comment that Selina one of the few people who Bruce does not feel he needs to put on a mask for. She does not find him intimidating as the rich and mysterious recluse Bruce Wayne, and is not afraid of him while he is Batman. Bale himself says in the segment that Bruce finds her "amusing", and Bruce feels comfortable enough to view her as an equal to himself.

Her importance to Bruce and their developing relationship may also play into the final scenes of the movie. Prior to being put into the prison by Bane, Bruce did not fear death. Once he realizes that he has to be, this drive helps him to make the jump to climb out of the pit. This fear of death also plays into why he is not able to die with the reactor, and instead fix the autopiolt, and in the end, be with Selina. Although it is only speculation, I think it can be fair to say that one of the reasons he had to live was to be with her.

In conclusion, Nolan added Selina as a character that would give Bruce the drive needed to not only become Batman again in order to later save Gotham, but also the female equal he longs for that will give him a will to live.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen Dark Knight Rises, but will try to answer it from a viewer's perspective

> 1. Need of a female counter-part of Batman. From Batwoman,Batgirl and 
>      Catwoman, Catwoman is more popular among Batman Fans.(At-least in movie world)
> 2. Need of a love interest of batman, Catwoman is not only a 
>      counter-part of Batman but also plays as a love interest of Batman.
> 3. Catwoman is a good character to play with, as she is a villain 
>      turned Antihero(or sometimes hero) in comics and who has interesting
>      twists and turns.
> 4. Its third and final of trilogy and now days one hero and one villain
>      is out of trend, so adding one more interesting character is always 
>      goood.

You can say that adding Robin could be a good choice but after the box office failure of [Batman and Robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_&_Robin_%28film%29) Film, producers might have tempted to just stick with Batman. And Robin always adds a little humor point which is not suited in Nolan's Batman Trilogy.

Comment: I think these are all secondary factors. The script actually required her. I missed it. Check @SteB's answer. Anyways +1 to make a list of other reasons! :)

Comment: Well Batman forever had Robin on it. They didn't want to feature Robin on this trilogy because christian bale was very much against it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: `From Batwoman,Batgirl and Catwoman, Catwoman is more popular among Batman Fans.` What makes you say that?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher in most of the cartoon series their is not batwoman and batgirl but there is catwoman. Similarly old movies also showed catwoman but not batgirl and batwoman. Everybody doesn't know about every single comics.Even catwoman also have her own movie too. So thats my reason for that

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Yes, Catwoman definitely has a solo movie in her kitty(_pun intended_). I reckon that does make her more popular, at least in the movie world.

Answer (score 3):

On a meta level, her addition picks up and plays with a typical James Bond "trope": the good Bond girl and the bad Bond girl. 
She's the counter-character to Miranda. First appearing as the bad girl, then after lots of ambiguity turning good. Whereas Miranda first appears to be a good female side-character that needs protection then revealing her actual evil leanings - at quite about the same time where Catwoman finally chooses to help (in contrast to being somewhat forced to).